# RXJS Angular 2 observable losing track if 'this'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Hello I have an anuglar 2 application and I am having trouble using observable for http requests. It works fine in general. I am just wondering, why does it seem to lose track of 'this'?

```
loginWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
    return this.http.post('auth/login', {email: email, password: password}, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError)
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    // console.log(body);
    if (body.token){
         this.saveToken(body.token);
         localStorage.setItem('token', body.token);
    }

    return body || {}
}
private saveToken(token: string){ 
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}
```

In the block

```
 if (body.token){
         this.saveToken(body.token);
         localStorage.setItem('token', body.token);
    }
```

I get the error

```
user.service.ts:54 TypeError: this.saveToken is not a function
at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/user/user.service.ts.UserService.extractData [as project] (user.service.ts:31)
at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:486)
```

What is the proper way to refer to other methods in a class using this pattern. I highly doubt we're supposed to go back  to `var self = this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
.map(this.extractData)
```

to

```
.map(data => this.extractData(data))
```

This is because the scoping of the above lines are different. The `this` inside the first (your original code) will point to the function itself, while the second, using the fat arrow function, will ensure that the `this` refers to the outer scope of the function.

Comment: Can you please add description why this fixes the issue

Comment: @xerotolerant you might to do the same for the `.catch` function if you want to access `this` within the `handleError` function

Comment: Yeah I'll do that too. Thanks.